# error evaluating network in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to load a saved model by saver and evaluate the output of the network over the test data, restoring a saved model and using the network as a function:

```
def model(x, x_size):
   with tf.variable_scope("my_net", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
       W1 = tf.get_variable('w1', [x_size, x_size], 
                initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())
       b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', [x_size], 
                initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer())  
       y1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, W1) + b1,'y1')
       return y1 


eval_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='eval_x', shape=[None, x_size])
eval_probs = model(eval_x, x_size)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('save_model/model.ckpt.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, "save_model/model.ckpt")
    probs = sess.run(eval_probs, feed_dict={eval_x: test_x})
```

The error I get is:

> FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value my_net/w1
>        [[Node: my_net/w1/read = IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@my_net/w1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a special operation to initialize variables like `w1`. An easy way to do this is to execute `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` after you create the session but before you use your variables.

Comment: Thanks! I thought `new_saver.restore` does initialization of them, because it has the values. Should I put `sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())` before the restore? How do I know I got the right values?

Answer (score 0):

From the code it seems that you are not passing any value for

```
x_size
```

so I don't think your variables get initialised.

Comment: I do. I just didn't write its value here in the message, same for test_x